# how to deal query that mysql json data type as condition with spring-data-jpa

Tags: mysql, json, spring-data-jpa

With `mysql`, there is a column used `json` data type. i want to execute query with the column as condition. With `Sql`, i can write it like bellow.

```
select * from user where json_extract(address,'$.city')= 'beijing'
```

But using spring-data-jpa, i don't know how to implement it. `JPQL` have no provided some api implement `json_extract`. And the `JpaSpecificationExecutor` of `jpa`  have not provide same function too. If someone know how to do it, please answer this question.

Comment: Try to use a `nativeQuery`...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@Query(value = "select * from user where json_extract(address,'$.city') = '?city'", nativeQuery = true)
List<User> findUsersByCity(String city);
```

I didn't check it.

Good luck

Comment: By this way, it really query with json_extract, but i lose way to product dynamic sql. So i used naticQuery， although it's a little tedious, but it does work.